# No carga correctamente el fichero php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hola estoy actualizando una página web, en el que tengo un formulario, se rellenan los datos necesarios y con javascript, en el momento de enviar el formulario, no se abre o no detecta bien el link.

En el momento de hacer clic en el botón editar, no se abre correctamente el link de la página que necesito que se abra.

En la barra del navegador aparece :

> http://localhost/fenix/EditarPruebaFrames.php?usuario=%3C?php%20echo%20$usuario%20?%3E

En caso de que todo haya salido bien, en la barra del navegador debe aparecer:

> http://localhost/fenix/EditarPruebaFrames.php?usuario=x5976ht

El error creo que está en esta línea

```html
   document.autform.action = "EditarPruebaFrames.php?usuario=<?php echo $usuario ?>";
```

```js
   function EditarPrueba(){
                var select_prueba = document.getElementById("prueba");
                var prueba = select_prueba.value;
                
                if ((prueba == "") || (prueba == null))
                    alert("No ha seleccionado ninguna prueba");
                else
                {
                     document.autform.action = "EditarPruebaFrames.php?usuario=<?php echo $usuario ?>";
                     document.autform.method = "POST";
                    document.autform.submit();
                    document.autform.action = "";
                    /*
                     document.getElementById("autform").action = "EditarPruebaFrames.php?usuario=<?php echo $usuario; ?>";
                    document.getElementById("autform").method = "POST";
                    document.getElementById("autform").submit();
                    document.getElementById("autform").action = "";*/
                }
            }
```

```html
  <form  class = "form-horizontal" name="autform" id="autform" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" target="EDICION">
 <!--
  Código del que se obtiene la "prueba"
 -->
 <input  class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="Editar" id="Editar" value="Editar" class="normal_text" onClick= "EditarPrueba();">
 </form>
```

¿alguna forma de que rediriga correctamente al fichero php?

gracias.

Comment: da la sensación de que no te esta interpretando el php. Donde estas ejecutando esa pagina? si por un casual es en tu equipo local debes tener un servidor php montado, apache+php...

Comment: si esta en un servidor local (bitnami), las otras paginas que tengo se abren correctamente, cabe mencionar que las que se abren correctamente se abren en una misma pestaña del navegador, pero cuando he tenido que modificar la pagina que digo, esta debe abrirse en otra pestaña y es donde no me redirige corractamente.

Answer (score 0):

creo que es algo de que no te interpreta bien el php. Sin embargo, en el form tienes un

```
action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>
```

que si esta funcionando, verdad?

Creo que podrías solucionarlo haciendo que la función EditarPrueba tenga un parámetro que sea el id de ese usuario. Algo como:

```
function EditarPrueba(userId){
                var select_prueba = document.getElementById("prueba");
                var prueba = select_prueba.value;

                if ((prueba == "") || (prueba == null))
                    alert("No ha seleccionado ninguna prueba");
                else
                {
                     document.autform.action = "EditarPruebaFrames.php?usuario="+userId;
                     document.autform.method = "POST";
                    document.autform.submit();
                    document.autform.action = "";
                    /*
                     document.getElementById("autform").action = "EditarPruebaFrames.php?usuario=<?php echo $usuario; ?>";
                    document.getElementById("autform").method = "POST";
                    document.getElementById("autform").submit();
                    document.getElementById("autform").action = "";*/
                }
            }
```

Y sustituir el input por:

```
<input  class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="Editar" id="Editar" value="Editar" class="normal_text" onClick= "EditarPrueba('<?php echo $usuario ?>');">
```

Comment: Gracias, tu respuesta me ha ayudado a saber por donde esta el problema. Respecto a tu pregunta el action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?> si funciona.  
Cuando lo hago de la forma en que tu dices me salta un error 

uncaught ReferenceError: x5976ht is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Otra cosa curiosa, es que tengo los scripts en ficheros .js y el echo usuario, no lo detecta como código php
mientras que si coloco los scripts en el mismo html, si me detecta como código php, no entiendo por que pasa eso.

Comment: Hola @Javr, si esta respuesta te ha ayudado, por favor, considera votar y aceptarla. Es la mejor forma de agradecer.

Comment: @Javr El fallo que mencionas es debido a que el id de tu usuario es una cadena, y en el javascript del boton debe ir entre comilla simple. lo he cambiado en la solución. De todas formas, estaria bien que comentaras cual era el problema, quizas la solución que te planteo no es la correcta.